# name 'set_hour' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Im working on this python code with tkinter. I would like to change the state of label set_hour to "active" by pressing 'j'. Everytime i run my code i get an error saying that set_hour is not defined. Do I need to use "self" here? and why can you explain please. Thank you

```
class SetClock:
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.myParent = parent

    self.current_datetime_label = tkinter.Label(root, text=datetime.datetime.now(), bg = "black", foreground="white").grid(row=1)
    #current_time_label.pack()

    self.menu_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Menu", bg="sky blue", foreground="black",width=18).grid(row=2)
    self.set_day = tkinter.Label(root, text="Set Day", bg="blue",foreground="white",width=9,state="active").grid(row=2, column=1)
    self.set_hour = tkinter.Label(root, text="Set Hour",bg="blue",foreground="white",width=9).grid(row=2, column=2)
    self.set_mintutes = tkinter.Label(root, text="Set Minutes", bg="blue",foreground="white",width=10).grid(row=2, column=3)
    self.exit_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Exit", bg="black", foreground="white").grid(row=2, column=4)

    self.day_menu_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Day",bg="sky blue",width=18).grid(row=3)
    #menu_label.pack(side="right")
    #current_time_label.pack()

def navigate_menu(event):
    current_pressed = str(event.char)
    print("pressed", current_pressed)
    if current_pressed is 'j':
        print("ok")
        set_hour.config(state="active")

root = Tk()    
#frame = Frame(root)
setclock = SetClock(root)
root.title("Set Clock")
root.minsize(width=500,height=500)
root.bind("<Key>",SetClock.navigate_menu)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `navigate_menu` as an instance method:

```
def navigate_menu(self, event):
    current_pressed = str(event.char)
    print("pressed", current_pressed)
    if current_pressed is 'j':
        print("ok")
        self.set_hour.config(state="active")
```

When you bind it, pass bound method instead:

```
root.bind("<Key>", setclock.navigate_menu)
```

Also, separate `Label` creation line and `grid()` line. Otherwise, `self.set_hour` become `None` because `grid()` method return `None`.

```
self.set_hour = tkinter.Label(root, text="Set Hour",bg="blue",foreground="white",width=9)
self.set_hour.grid(row=2, column=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`grid()` returns `None` so you have to do

```
self.set_hour = tkinter.Label(...)
self.set_hour.grid(...)
```